# How to change default java methods

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm facing some problems with my project  (probably because windows, antivirus or both).

What's happening is the following error:

```
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/404.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:389)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:40001)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:610)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: classFile.delete() failed
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:204)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:166)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:510)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.__compile(Compiler.java:379)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:41002)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
        ... 27 more
```

Looks like the file that classFile.delete() is trying to delete is in use.

We cannot add a exception in the antivirus....

I found a post from 2006 that says "My workaround was to modify the SmapUtil class. If the rename fails on the first try, it waits 50ms then retries (loops as needed). So far it always works on the second try after the 50ms delay."

My question is, where that SmapUtil class is located and how to edit that delete (and rename) methods?

I can't find this info anywhere

Thanks

Comment: this has nothing to do with windows, antivirus or anything of that. You don't get a runtime exception, it's compiletime. Your code doesn't compile, hence doesn't execute.

Comment: Well, you could find the sources online and try to compile it yourself. Then find out which jar it is located in and replace it. Or find the class first, decompile and change it, then recompile and replace the original. That's quite a complex process though and might break your Tomcat if not done right.

Comment: This is not related to anti-virus or windows , can you show the folder structure of you project

Comment: @Stultuske As I understand it "Unable to compile class for JSP" and "classFile.delete() failed" means that the compiler can't compile the jsp because it can't delete the old version first. So it's not necessarily a problem with the code itself.

Comment: @Thomas can you clear the tomcat work directory and start it again

Comment: Clean your workspace. It's probably another process temporarily accessing one of the file. No need to go overkill by recompiling the compiler

Comment: @TanmayNaik It's better to tag the OP in that comment.

Comment: @Stultuske it's actually at runtime. The code compiles and the server starts flawlessly, but when I try to open a page it gives me that error

Comment: @MarlonGriebeler with an error message like "Unable to compile", well ... it's still trying to compile something.
Normally, if you clean out your tomcat directory as Tanmay and jhamon have suggested, and re-deploy, it should work fine

Comment: I've deleted the entire work folder of tomcat. I think I already did that before, but let me start the server again (10+ minutes....)

Comment: Also, this is a hybris project, with a lot of custom add-ons. The project have over 6gb and 50k folders... Probably I can't expose them here because of company policies @TanmayNaik

Comment: The problem persists even after deleting the work directory. 
My guess is that whichever file that method is trying to delete, it's has been created really recently( like ms ago), and the antivirus or windows detects that new file and step in to scan/index it. So when the method tries to delete the file, it's in use by the antivirus/indexer.

Comment: @MarlonGriebeler Is it a specific page that you try to open which causes this, or is it all pages? Try to isolate the issue.

Comment: @Marlon Griebeler ok comment the code and check whether error occurs or not

Comment: @xtratic all of them

Comment: @TanmayNaik which code?

Comment: @Thomas really helped me to recompile tomcat :)) 
Thank you, changing the code and re-compiling worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "fix" it by changing that Tomcat method (delete and rename)

Looks like that whichever file it was trying to delete/rename, was being user by another process (likely antivirus)

So I cloned the source-code from Tomcat's Github, changed the class and voilá, it's working now.

That method was something like:

```java
    if ( !classPath.delete(..) )
      throw Exception...
```

then I changed for something like:

```java
    while ( !classPath.delete(..) && count < 10){
      Thread.wait(50);
      count++
    }

    if (count == 10) 
         Throw Exception
```

Comment: worth creating a bug report or so?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have Tomcat and Jasper configured for running in production.

To solve your specific issue you could **set the Jasper option `suppressSmap` to `true`** or **precompile your JSP files**, or both.

SMAP provides JSR-045 support for Jasper; It creates mappings from the generated bytecode back to the source JSP files to aid in debugging.

See [this page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration) for information on Jasper configuration.

Comment: I've edited the web.xml under tomcat/conf  with the supressSmap init param set to true and it didn't worked as well..

Comment: same as before, failed to delete()

Comment: That doesn't exactly make sense because if you suppressed Smap then `org.apache.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap` (which is the root of your exception) would not be called. The code in `JDTCompiler.java` is 
`/* JSR45 Support */
        if (! options.isSmapSuppressed()) {
            SmapUtil.installSmap(smaps);
        }`

Comment: What version of Jasper is this using? And are you sure you configured correctly?

Comment: I added  
``<init-param>
            <param-name>supressSmap</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>``

under 
``<servlet>
      <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
``

Comment: not sure how to determine the jasper version @xtratic
Also, if I do a ant all, it reverts my change at web.xml

Comment: I can't help you with further build or configuration difficulties since I have no information regarding your setup and this question would start getting pretty large and out of hand. I've helped as much as I can. Properly configuring your server and setting the options I mentioned should fix the issue. Best of luck.

Comment: The fact is: the project did run properly. After some windows update(&& antivirus policy update?) the project stopped working in all of our company machines. The project run fine in the production server as well as in the devs from the 3rd party company. All with the same project settings.